# Use dynamic port from Spring Boot in Geb configuration

Tags: java, spring, groovy, spring-boot, geb

Spring Boot's test framework has an option to select a random port for a test run with `'server.port:0'`. [The documentation suggests grabbing the port as a Spring `@Value`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-discover-the-http-port-at-runtime), but I'm wanting to use it to set the `baseUrl` in my `GebConfig.groovy`. Is there a way to access the dynamic port number from within the ConfigSlurper?

Comment: Where's is this dynamic port number stored?

Comment: this dynamic port will be only stored in spring `Environment`. I have never used groovy or geb, but does it make sense to pass this port number from spring to groovy via http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/ConfigSlurper.html#setBinding(java.util.Map) ?

Comment: @sodik There's no obvious way of getting a reference to the Spring environment or context from the config script.

Comment: sorry, I thought you are using geb with junit (as I am not very familiar with it, it was not obvious to me). if your spring app and geb is completely independent, it can either pick a port for yourself and then pass it to spring (and geb), or crazy solution if you use boot actuators, you can use `env` endpoint.

Comment: The Spring application and test harness aren't independent; Spring runs a captive application context that's accessible to test frameworks (in my case, I'm using Spock with the JUnit runner). The whole point of the exercise is to *avoid* picking a port myself, since Spring Boot will do it for me and avoid collisions.

Comment: maybe it would be useful if you described your test setup in more details so that others could know which advice is meaningful.

Comment: @sodik Absent any very specific questions, I believe that I have described the situation in sufficient detail for someone familiar with the technologies in question to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply override `GebSpec.createConf()` in a base spec:

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
int port

Configuration createConf() {
    def configuration = super.createConf()
    configuration.baseUrl = "http://localhost:$port"
    configuration
}
```

Comment: This isn't as clean as I'd like, but it mostly works. `createConf` does not get called for `Browser.drive`, but it seems like it works with page objects.

Comment: Why is it not as clean as you'd like? You cannot get hold of it in GebConfig.groovy because the value is not available in a global context but is injectable. Why would you ever use Browser.drive {} in a test? Another option would be to set a system property in setup() and then read it in GebConfig.groovy but to me it's less clean than my first solution because you depend on global state being set from a setup() method.

Comment: Not as clean because I have to extend a base class instead of externalizing the configuration. It would be possible for the execution context for the `GebConfig` script to provide access to the Spring context, but that would require upstream integration that might not be worth the entanglements. (And the static holder pattern doesn't work because of some execution ordering issues.)